# favicon wont change in root directory

Tags: magento-1.9

We have managed to change the favicon for the main website but when someone clicks on a link that opens a new window (application forms, etc) then the magento favicon is used. Every time I delete the favicon in my root directory and upload my own (with the same name) it overwrite it and restores the Magento one.

I have also now gone through and deleted every Magento favicon there is in my root directory and still it appears......

How change a i change it so on every change even the new windows that open up have my favicon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Step 2: Upload the Favicon to Your Store From the Admin panel, select
>   System > Configuration. In the Configuration panel on the left, under
>   General, select Design. Then, click to expand the HTML Head section.
>   Next to the Favicon Icon field, click the Browse button. Find and
>   select the favicon file to upload. When complete, click the Save
>   Config button.

Source:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/add-a-custom-favicon-for-your-web-store

---

**UPDATED**

A look around the class *Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head*

```
/**
 * Retrieve path to Favicon
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getFaviconFile()
{
    $folderName = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image_Favicon::UPLOAD_DIR;
    $storeConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/shortcut_icon');
    $faviconFile = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;
    $absolutePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/' . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;

    if(!is_null($storeConfig) && $this->_isFile($absolutePath)) {
        $url = $faviconFile;
    } else {
        $url = $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico');
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Would be a good point to check on pages you are experiencing the default icon.  Possibly the favicon.ico file in your template/theme may be getting used instead.

Some common paths of the `favicon.ico` file:

- /favicon.ico
- /media/favicon/favicon.ico
- /skin/`<package>`/`<template>`/favicon.ico

Comment: i have done that, so my favicon shows when im on the web site but when i click on the application form (which is brought up in a new window) the favicon switches back to magento one

Comment: Confirmed with browser and Magento cache cleared?

Comment: using chrome and yea i cleared the cache after

Comment: Updated answer.